# JQuery - Event Delegation to Anchor Tag is not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have an anchor element in HTML.

```
<a id = "btnUse-<?= $aGroupsInstance['seq'] ?>" class = "btnUse btnNormal" href = "#">
    <span>Use</span>
</a>
```

I am trying to bind a click event to it using JQuery's .delegate method. I am aware that it's deprecated but it's what I have to use anyway.

This is the JQuery code.

```
var oBody = $('body');
oBody.delegate('.btnUse', 'click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Anchor is clicked.');
});
```

This doesn't seem to work. I am frequently running into this whenever I try to bind an event to an  tag. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for the response.

Comment: .delegate is deprecated on v3. Consider using .on instead

Comment: "*I am aware that it's deprecated but it's what I have to use anyway.*" ... **Why**?

Comment: Apparently, this is the task I was given. I have to use JQuery version 1.4, I really want to use on but in this case, I have to use the delegate method because of certain circumstances.

Comment: Tell your lecturer that the method has been deprecated. He should not be promoting poor programming practices. You'll probably even get bonus marks for bringing it to his attention.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I am afraid it's not gonna work. However, I will make sure to still study the latest technologies despite this requirement. For now, I just have to make delegate work or any other method in JQuery 1.4 that could successfully bind en event to a column of anchor elements used as a button which were generated by a php foreach loop.

Comment: Is that all of your HTML? `delegate()` is adversely affected by nodes lower on the event chain if they have event handlers that have `return false` or `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Here goes a pen with jQuery 1.4 Hope it helps: https://codepen.io/Rechousa/pen/mxepNy

Comment: Nope, it is within a <td> tag . 
The structure is like this
<tr><td>Some Data..<td><a..></a>
Still, it is within a <div> tag. The code would be too long if I included it all but I'll try.

Comment: @PedroMartins . This one works, thanks.

Comment: I don’t think you even need an event delegate there. You can simply bind click event to the ele. Like $(“.btnUse”).click(function(){})

Comment: I used it in case that the need to dynamically append anchor elements arises.